# spring context error with processing xml

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have problem with processing `root-context` with really simple content. I just want to configure `camel-client` and `camel proxy` beans but I get:

> Error occured processing XML 'Provider
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1
>   counts   of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Class has two properties of
>   the same name "outputs" this problem is related to the following
>   location: at public java.util.List
>   org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition.getOutputs() at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition this problem is related to
>   the following location: at private java.util.List
>   org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition.outputs at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition '. See Error Log for more
>   details

This is my `root-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <camel:camelContext id="camel-client">

    </camel:camelContext>


    <!-- Camel proxy for a given service, in this case the JMS queue -->
    <camel:proxy
        id="serviceProxy"
        camelContextId="camel-client"
        serviceInterface="pl.test.Service"
        serviceUrl="jms:queue:test?transferException=true"/>


    <bean id="jboss" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="QueueConnectionFactory">

    </jee:jndi-lookup>

</beans>
```

I have `camel` dependancies in my `pom.xml`. Anyone could give me a hint where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Camel proxy [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/using-camelproxy.html) `<camel:proxy>` must be within `<camel:camelContext>`:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
    <camel:proxy
        id="serviceProxy"
        camelContextId="camel-client"
        serviceInterface="pl.test.Service"
        serviceUrl="jms:queue:test?transferException=true"/>
</camel:camelContext>
```